# How do I use regular expressions in Notepad++ to remove a starting string, ending string, and everything in between?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to strip data out of a .x file in Notepad++, and the data always starts with

```
FVFData  {
```

and ends with

```
}
```

with lines filled with numbers separated by commas or semicolons in between, like

```
258;
408;
1040987000,
1061457122,
```

Is there a simple way to do this in Notepad++ with regular expressions in the find/replace tool?

Comment: Sure, it's quite easy, but **what did you try?** Also what output do you want exactly?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, because usage of regular expressions is really confusing for me.  I'm an artist.

I have chunks that look like this:

    FVFData  {
        258;
        408;
        321,
         }

and I just want to get rid of them

Comment: Then learn regexes, try, and then come asking please. We don't get a stone boulder and come ask you how to make a statue, did we?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below site to make the validation expressions.

http://www.regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx

Before you implement the validations use the below sites to check that expressions. Once you got the successful with the site after that implement the expressions on you projects.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

[enter link description here](http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/)